# Syntax for pulling tuples and its elements out of a list?

Tags: python, string, tuples

Let's say I have

```
courses = ['French','Spanish','algebra','British literature']
subjects = ['language','math','English']
lista = [('French','language'),('Spanish','language'),('algebra','math'),('British literature','English')]
```

So that instead of a dictionary, I have tuples to match each course with its subject.

If I use `print '\n'.join([subject + ' in ' + course for (course,subject) in lista])`, I'd get a complete list in the form

```
language in French
language in Spanish
math in algebra
English in British literature
```

What would I write so that instead of printing the formatted contents of all of `lista`, I format only the first element `lista[0]`, so that it prints `"language in French"` instead?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Is that really important?  From the output, it is clear that the OP wants to join the second element of a tuple to the first with the string `'in'`.

Comment: @wflynny, I thought the OP was looking to create the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for us:

`print [subject +' in ' + course for (course,subject) in lista][0]`

Which outputs:

`language in French`

Just change the `[0]` to `[x]` where `x` is the element

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the one, you could do something like this:

```
' in '.join(lista[0][::-1])
```

`lista[0]` will give you the first element of `lista` and the `[::-1]` takes the reverse slice.

Answer (score 0):

I really must be misreading your question, because the way I understand it, you're looking for something as simple as

```
courses = ['French','Spanish','algebra','British literature']
subjects = ['language','math','English']
lista = [('French','language'),('Spanish','language'),('algebra','math'),('British literature','English')]
print lista[0][1] + ' in ' + lista[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the first tuple just unpack with `str.format` with numbering, putting the second element first:

```
print("{1} in {0}".format(*lista[0]))
language in French
```